# Physical vs. Virtual manipulatives in the high school classroom

Tags: secondary-education, reference-request, geometry, manipulatives

I notice that geometry students frequently have difficulty with representations of 3-dimensional objects in 2 dimensions. Today, we worked with physical manipulatives in order to help visualize where right triangles can occur in 3 dimensions in both pyramids and rectangular prisms (the focus is on fluency with the Pythagorean Theorem and noting its application in many contexts.) I chose to create physical manipulatives instead of finding online 3d manipulatives because *I felt as if the physical manipulatives would provide more insight than simply seeing a draggable, yet still 2d, projection.*

For clarity:

Physical manipulative in conjunction with 2d drawing:
[image: Photo of maipulative]

Some online examples of "virtual manipulatives": [1](https://www.learner.org/interactives/geometry/3d_pyramids.html) [2](http://www.learnalberta.ca/content/mejhm/index.html?l=0&ID1=AB.MATH.JR.SHAP&ID2=AB.MATH.JR.SHAP.SURF&lesson=html/object_interactives/surfaceArea/explore_it.html)

My question is: *Is there research supporting my intuition?* Are students who have difficulty translating between 2D and 3D more benefited by a physical model than a virtual manipulative, or the other way around?

Comment: My own experience is that weaker student benefit greatly from a physical model and get lost with the 2d virtual manipulatives.  Note that I taught gifted students but some of them were weak in visualization and only understood after handling the 3D model.

Answer (score 6):

This is not what you seek, because it compares two different
physical manipulatives, rather than physical vs. virtual.
But I find it interesting partly because 
my own research involves studying nets of polyhedra.

> Scott, Jacqui, Anton Selvaratnam, and Lynden Rogers. "Using Bendable and Rigid Manipulatives in Primary Mathematics: Is One More Effective Than the Other in Conceptualising 3D Objects from Their 2D Nets?." *TEACH Journal of Christian Education* 6.1 (2012): 10. ([Article link](http://research.avondale.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1028&context=teach))

---

[image: Manipulatives]

---

> ***Abstract excerpts***. The purpose of this study was to compare
>   the effectiveness of two different types of
>   manipulatives, bendable and rigid, as aids for
>   the conceptualisation of 3D solids from 2D nets...Contrary to initial expectations, the bendable
>   nets, although more attractive to pupils, did not
>   prove superior to the rigid variety. In fact, the
>   most noticeable advances in conceptualisation
>   followed teaching experiences using the rigid
>   nets.

They cite an article I couldn't find:

> Shaw, J. M. "Manipulatives enhance the learning of mathematics." Houghton Mifflin Mathematics. (2002).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a piece comparing virtual manipulatives to traditional teaching without manipulatives, in the context of community college remedial courses:

> Violeta Menil and Eric Fuchs, "Teaching Pre-Algebra and Algebra
>   Concepts to Community College Students through the Use of Virtual
>   Manipulatives", Improving Undergraduate Mathematics Learning, CUNY
>   Office of Academic Affairs, 2012. ([Link](http://www.cuny.edu/news/publications/imp.pdf))

Statistically significant improvements were found regarding exam performance and student attitude for prealgebra/arithmetic classes. None are found for either in elementary algebra classes.