# References on the effectiveness of manipulatives (virtual vs. physical)

Tags: reference-request, education-research, manipulatives

I am in need to find references for my thesis proposal. 
My topic is "Virtual manipulative versus physical manipulative: which way do students learn faster?".

Do you know any authors that worked on this topic or books about it?

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for your question. What do you mean by "support"? Are you mainly looking for earlier work on the subject on which you can base your proposal? Or, are you seeking practical help and funding? You can [edit] the question. (The former is more viable as a question here.)

Comment: I don't understand your title, and Google wasn't able to enlighten me. Could you perhaps explain a bit what you mean, and change the title to something more reflective of the question?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I made some minor tweaks to the question. If you do not like them, you can always change them.

Comment: What is a cyber manipulative? Do you mean something in the direction of embodied cognition? E.g., Dor Abrahamson ([faculty page](https://gse.berkeley.edu/people/dor-abrahamson)) does research on embodied design as related to math teaching/learning. Or do you mean math education software more generally? Or do you mean something like a FitBit? Or...? (I know what "physical manipulative" refers to -- e.g., base 10 blocks -- but its prefix is related to hands, and I'm not sure how that transfers to a "cyber" setting...)

Comment: Perhaps you mean virtual manipulatives.  I've never heard anyone in my school call them cyber manipulatives which might be what @BenjaminDickman and others were asking. Virtual Manipulatives are often used in K-9 with the Smart Board. For example, instead of using actual coins or base 10 blocks (physical manipulatives), the teacher might slide around coins on the smart board to make change or regroup using by moving base 10 blocks on the Smart Board.  I suggest you change cyber manipulatives to virtual manipulatives and give examples or links to virtual manipulative sites.

Comment: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10722/physical-vs-virtual-manipulatives-in-the-high-school-classroom

Comment: thank you for all the corrections and suggestion.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche the age group that I am interested is in grades 8 and 9. And in the Mathematical domain of Geometry.

Comment: @AirenErcikaSoberano, it seems that you're interested in the same age group and mathematical domain as those in the other question, so I'm voting to close your question as a duplicate.  Do not take this as a judgment that your question is "bad;"  I am voting to close it to avoid duplication of effort of those answering.

Comment: The linked "duplicate" question isn't exactly a duplicate; it asks about the high school classroom. Moreover, despite the "already has an answer" box above, it doesn't have an answer. The two "answers" there answer different questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a piece comparing virtual manipulatives to traditional teaching without manipulatives, in the context of community college remedial courses:

> Violeta Menil and Eric Fuchs, "Teaching Pre-Algebra and Algebra
>   Concepts to Community College Students through the Use of Virtual
>   Manipulatives", Improving Undergraduate Mathematics Learning, CUNY
>   Office of Academic Affairs, 2012. ([Link](http://www.cuny.edu/news/publications/imp.pdf))

Statistically significant improvements were found regarding exam performance and student attitude for prealgebra/arithmetic classes. None are found for either in elementary algebra classes.