# Why do we teach linear algebra in precalculus classes?

Tags: undergraduate-education, secondary-education, linear-algebra, precalculus

When I took precalculus, we learned about polynomials and how to factor them, we learned about trigonometry and lots of great and useful identities there, and we learned about matrices. They didn't call it linear algebra, they just called it matrices. We learned how to multiply them, we learned a whole bunch of ridiculous complicated methods to calculate determinants. We learned to solve systems of linear equations using Cramer's Rule, which is the mathematical equivalent of scrubbing a floor with a toothbrush. Never once did we actually learn what matrices were, how they would be useful, or why we would want to know any of this. I found the whole exercise to be tedious and pointless and quickly braindumped all of the matrix stuff as soon as the class was over.

Now, 20 years, a degree in math, a degree in physics, a career as a software engineer and data scientist, using linear algebra in building neural networks and many other places later, I am teaching a precalculus class, and I still have no idea what the point of teaching about matrices in it is. Like maybe some basic matrix/vector multiplication would be useful, applying them to systems of linear equations, but why do we force our students to painfully calculate determinants by hand when literally no one does this and the only reason to study these algorithms is if you are implementing a computer program to calculate them.

Don't get me wrong, I am a huge proponent of learning fundamentals and practicing working through problems by hand before you give it to your calculator. It is important to understand the concepts behind what you are doing and how they applies to the world around you so you can use them to solve problems in applications and they aren't just pure abstractions. Except that doesn't really work for matrices because we never bother to explain what they are or how to apply them, even less so for determinants.

Linear algebra is a very useful field used quite a lot in physics, engineering, computer science, and any number of other areas. And it has nothing to do with calculus. When I took a linear algebra class, I had to relearn all of these fundamental operations anyway, except there weren't any lengthy exercises in calculating determinants by hand because no one ever actually does that outside of a precalculus class. I have students asking me why we are learning this and I honestly don't have a good answer to give them. Why is it there?

Comment: It used to be in our precalculus syllabus, but I guess we ditched it at some point.

Comment: The precalculus connection is not clear to me. Are you questioning why these things are taught in precalculus? Would you be happy if they were taught elsewhere? Or are you questioning why they should be taught at all in any course?

Comment: @MahdiMajidi-Zolbanin I am questioning why they are taught in precalculus. They would be very little lost by saving them for linear algebra.

Comment: Re: "we never bother to explain what they are" -- I'm curious what you think they "are", if something other than a rectangular array of values?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins linear transformations. 3Blue1Brown gives a far better explanation than I got in 4 years of college. https://youtu.be/fNk_zzaMoSs

Comment: Re "*we learned a whole bunch of ridiculous complicated methods to calculate determinants*": Could you clarify which methods you are referring to?

Comment: *there weren't any lengthy exercises in calculating determinants by hand* -- I studied both precalculus and much of elementary linear algebra (in particular, all of the introductory matrices and determinants material typically covered in an elementary linear algebra course), this before calculators were widely available (around 1974-1975), and only very occasionally had to calculate a $4 \times 4$ determinant (and probably never anything higher unless symmetry, lots of zeros, or something else was involved), and $2 \times 2$ & $3 \times 3$ determinants take very little time to evaluate.

Comment: @JoelCroteau: That may be what they're _used for_, but that's not what they _are_. This is not something that takes a 16-course series to define; it's literally four words.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins that's like saying numbers are just symbols on a chalkboard. Describing matrices as just rectangular arrays without any context for how they are used does a massive disservice to your students.

Comment: Matrices were in our Alg. II book (~1978) but we didn't do it. Ditto for propositional calculus (logic). I would think that a justification would have the form, "because it is used in X or by Y, and they typically do not take linear algebra." (E.g. Y might be "chemists," but I don't know of such a justification. I figure something happened in the 20th cent. so that some class of people, who didn't take much math or maybe even go to college, had to calculate with matrices. Maybe the New Math ran amok.) Now data science is pushing linear lower down the curriculum, so maybe matrices are back.

Comment: One example use of matrix multiplication that shows why the process would ever be done is graphics rotation. Can be done with either multiplication of a 2x2 matrix by a list of points followed by addition or a 3x2 matrix with a list of triples where the third value is always 1. I do agree that with the classes I took (mid 90s) it was simply "here's matrix multiplication" without the slightest statement of why it would ever be done, even the most basic real-world application would have gone a long ways towards making it seem less than pointless.

Comment: @JoelCroteau I think you may like this then: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/awards/Axler-Ford-1996.pdf

Comment: Why the hate for Cramer's rule?   I've used this many times in my life,  for example,  when doing homework in my precalculus class.   I can't think of another example off the top of my head.

Comment: @JoelKeene just that solving a problem by calculating a whole bunch of different determinants seems impractical for all but the smallest of systems, and any such small system is much more easily dealt with by Gaussian Elimination.

Comment: I tried to help clarify your language so readers would understand you better. If you don't want to do that, _c'est la vie_.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Given the way we teach them, I'd say I'm a lot more likely to find someone who doesn't know that a matrix is a linear transformation than someone who doesn't know that it's a grid of numbers.

Comment: @JoelCroteau I was joking,  I actually had to look up Cramer's rule when you mentioned it, and I remembered how convoluted I thought it was back in high school.   Everything you said about it is exactly true.

Comment: @JoelCroteau: *"and any such small system is much more easily dealt with by Gaussian Elimination"* Well, this is true for matrices whose entries are explicitly known (unless in the $2 \times 2$-case, where Cramer's rule is very easy in any case). However, when you have a matrix that depends on several parameters (as it occurs e.g. often in physics) Gaussian elimination tends to be very tedious and can lead to a messy case-by-case analysis: as one doesn't know which matrix entries that occur during the elimination are non-zero, one doesn't know in which steps one has to swap two rows. [...]

Comment: [...] I think this is one of the main reasons why physicists and engineers tend to like Cramer's rule more than mathematicians do - simple modelling problems often lead to small matrices with a bunch of parameters.

Comment: "Some [precalculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precalculus) courses might differ with others in terms of content. For example, an **honors-level course might spend more time on conic sections, Euclidean vectors, and other topics needed for calculus**, used in fields such as medicine or engineering. A college **preparatory/regular class might focus on topics used in business-related careers, such as matrices**, or power functions." ... "generally coursework involves exercises rather than theory" (because **you can't really grade how well someone grasps a theory** or is simply using rote.)

Answer (score 16):

Vector algebra is a standard 3rd-semester calculus topic (e.g., see [OpenStax Calculus 3](https://openstax.org/details/books/calculus-volume-3), Ch. 2-3). This includes calculations of the dot product, cross product, and related values. Standard applications include calculating results of work, force, and business productions.

While this can be done purely algebraically (e.g., OpenStax does so), it's natural to express these operations in matrix notation, so calculus books may have some sections devoted to showing it in that form. Example on my bookshelf: this appears in Stein and Barcellos, *Calculus and Analytic Geometry* (5E, 1992), Sec. 12.5-12.7. Common exercises of the determinant and cross product include computing the areas of parallelograms, volumes of parallelipipeds, possibly crystallography, and torque. (In fact, calculation of parallelipiped volume from the end of the calculus sequence is one of the key half-dozen standard questions we use for assessment of our graduating math majors every year in my community college department.)

So presumably matrices appearing in a precalculus class are partly meant to set the stage for this use in calculus. Related, the precalculus course has covered solving linear equations (possibly by substitution and elimination), and it would be natural to show yet another option, the "next step", so to speak. And many of the students who take calculus will need linear algebra, so why not give them an introductory taste of all that content at the next level? (without calling the course something unwieldy like *Preparation for Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Related Mid-Undergraduate Mathematical Topics*, of course).

In addition, matrices also appear in the standard undergraduate discrete mathematics and data structures course texts as the basic way to represent general relations, graphs, and weighted graphs (and hence used in implementations for Euler circuits, Dijkstra's algorithm, Prim's and Kruskal's algorithms, etc.). Note this is a context in which matrices are *not* being used to represent linear transformations, so it's a case that highlights that's not *a priori* an essential part of the meaning of a matrix. In my own work, this is my own customary usage of matrices, for example.

So that's my understanding of the legacy of why those subjects have been included. If someone thinks that's poorly justified, or those topics have been squeezed out of those courses in recent years, then I could imagine coherent arguments for that.

Comment: Some previous familiarity with matrices and determinants is also helpful in introductory physics, electrical engineering, and mechanical engineering, courses. It's also one of the many latter-in-the-course topics that are often jettisoned due to time constraints (e.g. probability, math induction, rotation of coordinates and conics whose directrix or semi-major/minor axes or asymptotes are not parallel to the coordinate axes, partial fractions, etc.), but probably kept more often than the others because of Cramer's rule for solving $2 \times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ systems of linear equations.

Comment: Personally, I managed to graduate from college with a bachelor's of science, including a course in multivariable calculus, without *anyone*, at any point in my formal education, ever having communicated to me the interpretation of matrices as linear transformations of the plane. I had to learn it by watching a YouTube video. Presumably it was an instance of the [you'll learn it next year](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2d/d5/70/2dd5709f3000ae2c72b7de6b7fe20b83.jpg) problem, but it still amazes me that "how to calculate a determinant" was considered more important.

Comment: @Kevin: Matrices as linear transformations (actually, as *representations* of linear transformations, and not just of the plane) is a central topic in elementary linear algebra courses that physical science and some social science majors take (often in 2nd year; this being U.S. perspective) -- see "first level" in [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/433944/13130). Depending on the multivariable calculus course (here I mean the end of the elementary calculus sequence, and not advanced calculus), this aspect may be only be briefly mentioned or it may form a major theoretical arc.

Comment: Doesn’t linear algebra also directly intersect with solving differential equations?

Comment: "by the time the students get to differential equations, they are supposed to be proficient in a bunch of previous material, and they aren't." [How to get past the "mystique" of Maths](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/14234/how-to-get-past-the-mystique-of-maths)

Answer (score 9):

The College Board made curriculum decisions for their new AP Precalculus course that align with sentiments you express. The course is divided into four units, where unit four is titled *Functions Involving Parameters, Vectors, and Matrices*. But unit 4 is **not** assessed on the exam. Here is an excerpt from their [Course and Exam Description document](https://apcentral.collegeboard.org/media/pdf/ap-precalculus-course-and-exam-description.pdf):

> Units 1, 2, and 3 topics comprise the content and conceptual
> understandings in which colleges and universities typically expect
> students to be proficient, in order to qualify for college credit
> and/or placement. Therefore, these topics are included on the AP Exam.
> Unit 4 consists of topics that teachers may include based on state or
> local requirements.

Answer (score 8):

Because derivatives are linear operators.

Comment: +1 I think this is quite an important point (although the answer might be better - and better received - if you add a bit of elaboration). The claim that linear algebra "has nothing to do with calculus" in the question seems unwarranted since Jacobi matrices are important for calculus in several variables.

Comment: Also with the hate on Cramer's rule in the question, while I agree that it is not really a good practical tool for inverting matrices, there is a plethora of connections between subdeterminants and surface elements, the transformation behaviour of normals and so on. Maybe the question should rather be, why are those connections not better highlighted in this and in later classes?

Answer (score 0):

> Linear algebra is a very useful field used quite a lot in physics, engineering, computer science, and any number of other areas. And it has nothing to do with calculus.

It is incorrect to say linear algebra has nothing to do with calculus: linear algebra is *all over the place* in multivariable calculus. Maybe you meant to say that linear algebra has nothing to do with single-variable calculus.

I too saw some matrix algebra (in the $2 \times 2$ case) in my high school precalculus course. I never thought much about why anyone decided to put it  there. Possibly it was included to expose students to some matrix work so the concept of a matrix would not be completely new if/when the students get to multivariable calculus. Or the person designing the curriculum knew that matrices are a mathematical tool that also comes up in later coursework not relying on calculus, e.g., some "math for business/economics majors" courses that I've seen have a unit on matrices: consider the Leontief input/output model.

You compare Cramer's rule to "scrubbing a floor with a toothbrush". For the purposes you saw of it, I understand that impression. But in higher mathematics (at the level only math majors would see), Cramer's rule is genuinely useful. It is one of the methods that implies algebraic numbers form a field, it shows ${\rm GL}_n(\mathbf R)$ is a topological group, and it shows ${\rm GL}_n(K)$ is an algebraic group for (algebraically closed) fields $K$.

Comment: "higher mathematics at the level only math majors would see" is precisely the sort of thing we should not be forcing every high school student to learn.

Comment: @JoelCroteau I agree that those applications I mentioned are not something to be taught to high school students. I mentioned them only to point that Cramer’s rule is still relevant in higher math, rather than being something that has become totally obsolete for everyone. If Cramer’s rule were taught in HS, it should be to do something at that level. Many things in math can be thought about in a basic way and advanced way.